# Splitting a Netfilter packet

Tags: c++, linux, networking, netfilter

I want to be able to, when a packet comes in, split it into two packets (two different destinations in ip header) and pass this back to netfilter.
I am using c++ if that helps.

Is this possible in any way?

Thanks

Comment: Do you wish to send 2 identical (except for destination address) packets, or split into 2 or 3 parts and send each part to a different destination?

Comment: Different destination

Comment: But do you want them to be identical or split?

Comment: Ah, sorry for misunderstanding. I want two compleatly different packets

Comment: But do you want the 2 packets to be identical except for the destination IP address?

Comment: No, the two packets will have different payloads as well as different destination fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the best way to do this is by sending the data by means of raw packets, as long as you manually fill in the ip header yourself.